# laptops which are suitable for heavy Image and video processing

Tags: laptop, graphics-cards, processor, high-end

I am a graduate student and My thesis is based on deep learning, vision, video and Image processing. I am going to do heavy computing and processing. I am looking for a compatible laptop which has a fast GPU-enabled laptop. CUDA enabled on an NVIDIA GPU with 1 TFOPS would be a good choice. Also, it must have SSD. Anything by hp, Dell, Microsoft, Acer. do you have any recommendations? Are there any websites that introduce the best laptops? and new technologies?
which one do you think is the best "HP, DELL, Microsoft or Acer"?
my budget is $CAN 1800

Comment: What's your budget?

Comment: @JMY1000. It is 2000 Canadian dollars.

Comment: Just wondering why the number of "1 TFOPS", where did you get that number that you think that's what you need? Even lower-end graphics cards like the 1050 do 1 TFOPS.

Comment: Do you care much (if at all) about battery life, weight, or screen? Do you plan to do any gaming? Do you care if it looks "gamer-y"?

Comment: @ Yisroel Tech. my professor told me that number. I do not know how can I check the TFOPS. I could not find this abbreviation in the computer. how can I check it?

Comment: Here is a bit of a simple explanation of what TFlops is https://www.gamespot.com/articles/what-is-a-teraflop-and-what-does-it-mean-for-the-x/1100-6440802/. Doing a simple Google search for something like "TFlops rating for Nvidia <fill in the care name>" should give you some idea of a cards rating.

Comment: guys pls look at this https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/9448/which-laptop-suites-heavy-programming   and leave your comments.

Answer (score 2):

If not for the price limit I would've told you to go with at-least something like the [**MSI GT63 TITAN-046**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B07CDD2259), which is over $2500... Or even [**this Asus
ROG STRIX**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B078HRSQLW) for $1,719.

For your budget, though I think the best you can get is the **Acer Predator** with an **NVIDIA GTX 1070**. Available in both a [**15-inch screen size**](https://amzn.to/2J9xYwy) as well as a [**17-inch model**](https://amzn.to/2NE252A).

Answer (score 0):

https://www.dell.com/en-us/gaming/alienware-laptops?~ck=mn

Alienware has gaming laptops which have the best GPU.

https://www.dell.com/en-us/shop/dell-laptops/new-alienware-17/spd/alienware-17-laptop/dkcwcflg044

You could contact them if you wanted more, but cost goes through the roof.

Comment: could you please explain what is  TFOPS exactly?

Comment: @nikki2  Trillion Floating-Point Operations Per Second.  High end video cards have 2000-8000 cores, so with each core operating at full throttle more than 1 trillion floating point operations per second can be done.

Comment: do you think 1 TFOPS is enough for deep learning and Image processing? since my budget is about 1500 USD.

Comment: Are you doing your analysis in real time, say from a webcam, or post as in processing a pre-recorded video?  Pre-recorded video the process can take as long as it wants, within your project deadline.  However, real-time, needs more because it has certain deadline it has to meet.  I don't know enough about deep learning or your project to give you a minimum requirements.

Comment: I'm considering -1-ing this. Alienware by no means is the only manufacturer of laptops with high-end GPUs, and blanket recommending them is ignoring a lot of other good laptops.

Comment: It would be real time.

Comment: @JMY1000  Sadly I don't know the other brand name that include 1080 level graphics.  Please tell all of us, and I will make a note for future reference.

Comment: There are several that do, all the gaming ones (Asus ROG, MSI, Origin PC, Razor, HP Omen, Acer Predator). But $1500 US is just too little for that anyhow. The link you put (to the NEW ALIENWARE 17) starts at 3K US! You can not even get a 1070 GPU for that price.

Comment: @YisroelTech is correct for $1500 a 1070 is all your going to get.  I wish the OP had put there price restriction out before I had made my suggestion.