# which laptop suites heavy programming?

Tags: laptop, graphics-cards, processor, development, 3d-display

I am going to do heavy computing and processing like programming. I am looking for a compatible laptop which has a fast GPU-enabled laptop. CUDA enabled on an NVIDIA GPU. Also, it must have SSD. Anything by hp, Dell, Microsoft, Acer.

I have searched and found these laptops, which one do you think is the best?

Dell:  New XPS 15:

https://www.dell.com/en-ca/shop/compare?ocs=nxps1570_bt_s1656e,nxps1570_bt_s1661e
We understand that the only difference between these two is the display.

Microsoft:
Surface Laptop (Intel Core i7, 16GB RAM, 512GB) - Graphite Gold - DAL-00019:

HP:
OMEN by HP 17-w018ca Notebook PC, i7-6700HQ, 2.6GHz, 2 TB, BLK
https://www.amazon.ca/HP-17-w018ca-Notebook-i7-6700HQ-2-6GHz/dp/B01M0L5BQ8/ref=sr_1_14?s=pc&ie=UTF8&qid=1531253277&sr=1-14

HP 15.6" ZBook 15 G4 Premium Mobile Workstation (Intel i7-7700HQ Quad-Core, 16GB RAM, 1TB HDD + 512GB SSD, 15.6" Matte Full HD 1920 x 1080, NVIDIA Quadro M1200 4GB, Thunderbolt 3, Win 10 Pro)
https://www.amazon.ca/HP-Workstation-i7-7700HQ-Quad-Core-Thunderbolt/dp/B07CCYRFWQ/ref=sr_1_6?s=pc&ie=UTF8&qid=1531253771&sr=1-6&th=1

HP ProBook 470 G5 17.3'' Premium Business Laptop PC (Intel 8th Gen i7 Quad Core Processor, 16GB RAM, 1TB HDD + 512GB SSD, 17.3" HD 1600x900 Display, NVIDIA GeForce 930MX, USB-C, WiFi, BT, Win 10 Pro)
(P-SPEES)
https://www.amazon.ca/HP-ProBook-Business-Processor-1600x900/dp/B07B5Y5RGB/ref=sr_1_7?s=pc&ie=UTF8&qid=1531250221&sr=1-7&th=1

Comment: The XPS 15 option handedly outmatches the other laptops with a 1050Ti. All of the computer options are more than adequate for running heavy IDEs. I'm curious as to why you are aiming for such high end discrete graphics cards if you're planning on doing programming and heavy computing. Technically you'd benefit from a computer by allocating your budget away from high end dedicated graphics in exchange for better multi-threaded processors, although your processor selection is probably already overkill for your purposes. You may be overpaying for all intents and purposes.

Comment: do you have any option in your mind? pls recommend me

Comment: What kind of programming are you doing? I know you said you'd be using CUDA, but that still leaves a lot of wiggle room.

Comment: @JMY1000 . Deep learning  for detection something in the video

Answer (score 1):

As I said earlier if you are going to choose from your list the Dell XPS configuration is best positioned to suit your needs as it has the best processor among your choices. However, I think that it is a bit overvalued, and thus; I was able to beat out your prices.

Here are some laptops you could purchase today that are more than enough for programming and computing. I also fit in some pretty decent desktop GPUs since I'm not really close to stretching your budget. Each option includes a 1 TB HDD, and blazing fast 128 GB NVMe SSDs. You could also play triple A games on these laptops without two much trouble, so heavy 3D game development should be a breeze on these laptops.

I believe that the shipping for the laptops are free, and as far as I could tell there shouldn't be any customs import fees.

### [MSI GL62M 7RDX-NE1050i5 $899.99 CAD (MSRP: $1,049.99)](https://www.newegg.ca/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16834154734&ignorebbr=1)

[image: MSI GL62M 7RDX-NE1050i5]

- Discrete NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 **2 GB** GDDR5
- i5 7300HQ, you can Upgrade to the i7 variant for +$150
- 8 GB Memory

This laptop should meet your needs if you're looking to save money. The i7 variant of this computer will give you about [47% more multi-core performance according to user benchmarks](http://cpu.userbenchmark.com/Compare/Intel-Core-i7-7700HQ-vs-Intel-Core-i5-7300HQ/m211019vsm223877) and may be worth the upgrade for your usage scenario.

### [MSI GL Series GL63 8RC-068 $1,469.99 CAD (MSRP: $1,499.99)](https://www.newegg.ca/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16834154821)

[image: MSI GL Series GL63 8RC-068]

- GeForce GTX 1050 **4 GB** GDDR5
- i7 8750H
- 16 GB Memory

This option has a lot more RAM that you are unlikely to come close to filling up unless you like running multiple virtual machines alongside a heavy IDE, even then you won't fill that up. **The [i7 8750H benchmarks](http://cpu.userbenchmark.com/Compare/Intel-Core-i7-7700HQ-vs-Intel-Core-i7-8750H/m211019vsm470418) suggests that it will outperform the i7 7700HQ by 31% in general use scenarios and 53% in multi-core scenarios making it the better option for heavy computing.** In addition, should you want it, you can select this configuration to have a GTX 1050 Ti for +$130 dollars if you feel so inclined. [The benchmarks for the 1050 Ti](http://gpu.userbenchmark.com/Compare/Nvidia-GTX-1050-Ti-vs-Nvidia-GTX-1050/3649vs3650) suggest an improvement of about +14% in FPS over the non-titan variant.